# Combine arrays inside object

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

So i have a javascript code which merge the the orders from the array into 1.

```js
function mergeOrder(data) {
  // write your code here
  let result = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < data[i].orders.length; j++) {
      result.push(data[i].orders);  
      break;
    }
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(
  mergeOrder([  
    {
      restaurant: "MekDun",
      orders: [
        ["Burger", 200],
        ["Kentang", 130],
        ["CocaCola", 400],
        ["IceCream", 186],
      ],
      reviewers: 140,
    },

    {
      restaurant: "Lawmore",
      orders: [
        ["Ayam", 126],
        ["CocaCola", 206],
        ["Burger", 368],
        ["IceCream", 80],
      ],
      reviewers: 260,
    },

    {
      restaurant: "Burger Queen",
      orders: [
        ["Ayam", 85],
        ["CocaCola", 150],
        ["Burger", 450],
        ["Kentang", 20],
      ],
      reviewers: 80,
    },
  ])
);
```

I get this output:

```
[
  [
    ['Burger', 200],
    ['Kentang', 130],
    ['CocaCola', 400],
    ['IceCream', 186],
  ],
  [
    ['Ayam', 126],
    ['CocaCola', 206],
    ['Burger', 368],
    ['IceCream', 80],
  ],
  [
    ['Ayam', 85],
    ['CocaCola', 150],
    ['Burger', 450],
    ['Kentang', 20],
  ],
];
```

How do i make the output into this which basically combining the arrays into 1 instead of grabbing each array

```
 [
  [
    'Burger',   200,
    'Kentang',  130,
    'CocaCola', 400,
    'IceCream', 186
  ],
  [
    'Ayam',     126,
    'CocaCola', 206,
    'Burger',   368,
    'IceCream', 80
  ],
  [ 'Ayam', 85, 'CocaCola', 150, 'Burger', 450, 'Kentang', 20 ],
 ]
```

I tried changing the result push or putting another for to grab the orders object but this is what my output looks like. I even tried putting random things like adding another for or grabbing one by one but it doesn't work. I'm not allowed to use other functions like `concat()` or `flatten()`.

Comment: But, why do you want to get a flat array of name and numbers. Isn't useful if it they are grouped seperately?

Answer (score 0):

You could map flat `orders`.

```js
function mergeOrder(data) {
    return data.map(({ orders }) => orders.flat());
}

console.log(mergeOrder([{ restaurant: "MekDun", orders: [["Burger", 200], ["Kentang", 130], ["CocaCola", 400], ["IceCream", 186]], reviewers: 140 }, { restaurant: "Lawmore", orders: [["Ayam", 126], ["CocaCola", 206], ["Burger", 368], ["IceCream", 80]], reviewers: 260 }, { restaurant: "Burger Queen", orders: [["Ayam", 85], ["CocaCola", 150], ["Burger", 450], ["Kentang", 20]], reviewers: 80 }]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this It's Working fine**

```js
function mergeOrder(data) {
  let result = [];
   data.map((d) => {
       let arr = []
       d.orders.map((order) => {
           arr.push(order)
       })
       result.push(arr)
   })
  return result;
}

console.log(
  mergeOrder([  
    {
      restaurant: "MekDun",
      orders: [
        ["Burger", 200],
        ["Kentang", 130],
        ["CocaCola", 400],
        ["IceCream", 186],
      ],
      reviewers: 140,
    },

    {
      restaurant: "Lawmore",
      orders: [
        ["Ayam", 126],
        ["CocaCola", 206],
        ["Burger", 368],
        ["IceCream", 80],
      ],
      reviewers: 260,
    },

    {
      restaurant: "Burger Queen",
      orders: [
        ["Ayam", 85],
        ["CocaCola", 150],
        ["Burger", 450],
        ["Kentang", 20],
      ],
      reviewers: 80,
    },
  ])
);
```

Comment: no thats not the output i want sadly

Comment: can you please share your output ?

Comment: ```
[
  [
    [ 'Burger', 200 ],
    [ 'Kentang', 130 ],
    [ 'CocaCola', 400 ],
    [ 'IceCream', 186 ]
  ],
  [
    [ 'Ayam', 126 ],
    [ 'CocaCola', 206 ],
    [ 'Burger', 368 ],
    [ 'IceCream', 80 ]
  ],
  [
    [ 'Ayam', 85 ],
    [ 'CocaCola', 150 ],
    [ 'Burger', 450 ],
    [ 'Kentang', 20 ]
  ]
]
```

Comment: I've just edit my answer Is it useful for you ? Check my new Answer

Comment: Check it my answer @RizkyAmanatama